# In Word, how to make it so selecting doesn't also select the newline characters?

Tags: microsoft-word

If I set my cursor in the middle of the line, then hit `Shift+End`, Word will select the carriage return and newline character too.

What settings would I need to change in Word 2013 in order to make it stop selecting before the newline and carriage return, instead of after them?

**added**

I know I can do shift+end+(still holding down shift)+LeftArrow. I want to not have to do that. I want a setting that makes shift+end not include the CRLF. Is there a setting for that?

Comment: Related: [How to make Microsoft Word selection behave like it would in a plain text editor](http://superuser.com/questions/962710/how-to-make-microsoft-word-selection-behave-like-it-would-in-a-plain-text-editor)

Comment: Note: "ctrl+shift+end" is 'select until end of document', it's just "shift+end" to select to the end of the current line, I'm going to assume you're talking about selecting until the end of the line, not the document. :)  AFAIK there's no easy way to stop it (you'd probably have to write a macro to replace the existing shift-end action).  You are telling it you want to select everything until the end of the line, and the CR is part of the line.  Why not just do Shift+End, Shift+LeftArrow (to move the selection end back on character)?

Comment: Techie007, I already do the the shift+LeftArrow. I want to not have to do that. Many Text editors will stop before the newline. After all, if you stop after it, you are no longer on the current line. Mostly it's a convenience thing since 9/10 time I don't want that EOL character.

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried the suggestions in the other post you linked to, but they didn't work. I'll keep trying variations.

Comment: None of the comments provide a workable solution.  I'd love to see this one answered, too (if there's an answer other than "not possible").  Stupid newlines are not part of the selected text, unless you do a multi-line selection!  How can this work on any editor but word?

Answer (score 2):

To select text without also selecting the newline character, go to File > Options and click Advanced. Clear the "Use smart paragraph selection" setting and click OK.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This has bugged me for a long time, thank you! (Not sure why it needs a citation, surely the whole point is users will upvote the answers which work)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a (not smart) solution:

1. Click the "Show paragraph marks" icon in the Home menu (looks almost like a pi symbol).
2. Position the cursor at the start of the words you want to select, eg start of a line.
3. Press Shift+End
4. Keep Shift down and press 
   Voila - You can select with Ctrl+C

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my answer abnove was spoiled during submit because of a "less than " sign and I cannot delete it.

In fact you don't need to use "Show paragraph marks".

All you need to do is

1. position cursor
2. Press Shift + End
3. Keep Shift down and press (Left arrow)

Comment: You can [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1709465/edit) your previous answer though...

Comment: Make sure you read the comments on the main thread as this is already called out there. Additionally, this doesn't actually answer the question, as it doesn't change the behavior of hitting shift+end.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the most generalizable workaround for kill text through end of line is:

1. Position cursor
2. Hit enter create a new paragraph
3. Shift+end
4. Backspace.

I've been using shift+end followed by shift-left for years, but I found a case where it does not work: outline view.

As observed in the question, Office interfaces greedily grab linefeed/carriage returns, and this behavior is recapitulated when hitting shift+end in Word's outline view. However, outline view has a quirk that breaks the usual workaround: any action that selects the end-of-paragraph will concommittantly select the entire bullet/paragraph. This remains true when you've unselected "smart selection" options in the File->Options->Advanced page. Once you've selected the entire bullet/paragraph, shift+left arrow now deselects it and brings the cursor to its beginning.

The above workaround results in the desired "kill line" behavior, and it should work across Office products.

ETA: If you're not intending to delete but adding style or something, and you never use outline view, then you can replace step 4 with your something and add a step 5 which is home and backspace.

Comment: The explanation for this bizarre behavior is known only to the RNG. This workaround feels unnatural to me. I'm used to certain UNIX environments where `ctrl-k` removes the linefeed, but I'd typically add the linebreak in after killing instead of before.

Comment: Currently using Office 365 on Windows 10 Business