# How can I stop Word from "intelligently" selecting the carriage return?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I have found this question previously asked, but always left unanswered. I have found [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/962710/how-to-make-microsoft-word-selection-behave-like-it-would-in-a-plain-text-editor) which has been of great help for my sanity, but still, when I select an entire line, say by doing shift+end, it does this insanity:

[image: Word sucks and I hate it]

Is there any way to stop this. I'm constantly working off of templates and when Word does this, it results in changes of formatting and it's all bad and I hate it.

Comment: After shift+home keep shift down and press left arrow.

Comment: @MátéJuhász I am aware of this. I want this to not be necessary in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

File -> Options -> Advanced then deselect "Use smart paragraph selection"

Comment: Thank you for the response, but this is not the same as the carriage return issue I am describing.

Comment: This answer worked for me in Office 365 but only after I stopped/restarted Word.

Comment: In office 365 turning this off does not affect Outline View :( very frustrating